# How do I return an empty array / array of length 0 in perl?

Tags: perl

I want to return an empty *array*, not an empty *list*.

I have a sub that returns an array of things. I want to be able to do this with it:

```
my $count = scalar getArray();
```

I did it like this:

```
sub getArray {
    if ( !isGood() ) {
        return ();
    } else {
        my @array = calculateSomehow();
        return @array;
    }
}
my $count = scalar getArray();
```

I had a suprise when `!isGood()` and `$count` becomes `undef`, not `0`! After reading [perlfaq4](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq4.html#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array), I realize that this is because getArray() is evaluated in scalar context and hence the *list* `()` is evaluated as a scalar, and `scalar( () )` is `undef`, while `my @array; scalar( @array )` is 0.

The question now becomes: How do I most elegantly return an empty *array*, so that `$count` is `0` if `!isGood()`? I've only come up with:

```
# This is kind of kludgy: Dereference an anonymous array ref. Really?
return @{[]};
```

or

```
# I use a temporary variable for this. Really?
my @empty;
return @empty;
```

Aren't there any cleaner / more elegant ways of returning an *array* of length 0 (empty *array*) or some other way of making `scalar getArray()` evaluate to `0`?

Comment: Do you find `return my @empty` cleaner or more elegant?

Comment: Thanks @choroba  - yes, I do!

Comment: subs always return lists.

Comment: As @ysth correctly observes, you cannot return an array from a subroutine, only a list.  The array evaluates to a list in list context and to a scalar in scalar context.

Comment: Thanks, @tchrist. Had you made this into an answer, I would've adccepted that instead. This explains what is really going on.

Comment: Well, the accepted answer could be clearer about this, since it risks propagating the misunderstanding that arrays are returnable. Rather, when you use `return @array` then you are returning the array’s interpolated list of scalar elements in list context and the scalar count of those list elements in scalar context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably clearest if you just return an array in both cases:

```
sub getArray {
    my @array;
    @array = calculateSomehow() if isGood();
    return @array;
}
```

But to modify your original code in the minimal way, use `wantarray`.

```
if (!isGood()) {
    return wantarray ? () : 0;
}
```

Comment: `my ... if` has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @choroba That would astonish me if true.  Please provide a reference.

Comment: [perlsyn](http://p3rl.org/perlsyn): NOTE: The behaviour of a my, state, or our modified with a statement modifier conditional or loop construct (for example, `my $x if ...` ) is undefined. The value of the my variable may be undef, any previously assigned value, or possibly anything else. Don't rely on it. Future versions of perl might do something different from the version of perl you try it out on. Here be dragons.

Comment: Well, huh.  Seems like I've seen code like that in many places, and the semantics here seem unambiguous enough.  But it's easy enough to fix.

Comment: With `my` (and Co) the symbol does get introduced, regardless of anything else.  Then what to do with it in a conditional?  When `my $x;` is given first, there is a well defined 'value' for it (`undef`), and the following conditional assignment may be skipped.

Comment: `my` has both a compile time effect (mentions of that variable name from the following statement to the end of the block (or to the statement after another declaration of it) bind to that lexical), and a runtime effect (scheduling the value to be cleared and the variable to be unavailable when the enclosing scope is exited).  Making it conditional suppresses the runtime effect, with sometimes surprising consequences. But this is an implementation detail and subject to change, hence the warning in the doc.

Comment: The undefined behavior of a postfix conditional on a lexical definition is [solved in v5.30 by completely disallowing it](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2019/07/no-more-false-postfix-lexical-declarations-in-v5-30/).

Answer (score 2):

*A subroutine can only return a list (of scalars) in Perl.*

*If an array variable is given to `return` it is evaluated and either a list of its elements is returned, if the sub is called in a list context, or its length (number of elements), if the sub is called in a scalar context. (Originally stated in comments, only summarized here in this edit.)*

*The closest to "returning an array" is to return a reference to it.*

---

Return a reference and you can get the array size (0 if empty) in one call, by dereferencing.

```
sub getArray {
    # calculate ...
    return \@results;         # @results may be empty  ( or [@results] )
}

$rres = getArray();
my $count = @$rres;           # gives 0 if ref is to empty array

my $cnt   = @{ getArray() };  # or without storing the return
```

You *can* use `scalar` above, if you wish, but you don't need to. This is also alike to returning a pointer to an array (even if empty), if that's what you had in mind by requiring an "empty array."

If you want to go this route but to single out the `not-good`

```
sub getArray {
    return if !isGood();  # returns undef
    # calculate ...
    return \@results;     # scalar whether the list be empty or not
}
```

---

Using context may help -- either get your list from the array (empty or not), or `0` for a scalar

```
sub getArray {
   if (!isGood() ) {
       return (wantarray) ? () : 0;
   }
   else { }  # your code
}
my @results = getArray() # returns a list, possibly empty
my $count = getArray();  # returns 0
```

Comment: Sorry, zdim, @Sean beat you to it! ;-)

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch  I see this ... by 17 seconds??

Comment: It turns out, by the (easy) correction that he needed ... he didn't

Comment: Your last edit again lets you be second ;) , but good that the thing about wanting to return an *array* now has a clear answer. In perlsub, we find [*The Perl model for function call and return values is simple: all functions are passed as parameters one single flat list of scalars, and all functions likewise return to their caller one single flat list of scalars*](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#DESCRIPTION "perlsub - Perl subroutines - Perldoc Browser").